# How to share a global variable between server and client code in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, global-variables

I'm trying to share a varible between server and client code.I have declared the global variable in /lib/environment.js

```
test = null;
```

In the server/main.js,I'm updating this variable when I receive a POST request.

```
test ="hello";
```

The problem is if I try to access the same variable inside client/main.js file, the value doesn't get updated to the new value.
I'm not understanding this behavior.

Comment: Well, the client (browser) and the server don't share the variables (even if they include the same file) as they are separate procesess, which don't usually operate on the same machine. AFAIK, you would have to use WebSockets or something like SignalR to send a value from server to the client

Comment: Thanks @JakubJankowski

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Meteor works in such an integrated way, it makes you think this is possible, but the server process will run on a server, and the client runs in the browser. Easy to forget that.

To share data, the easiest way is to use a collection, which if published and subscribed, gives you the same effect as a global variable.

Otherwise you can use Meteor.call() to pass data from client to server.